# Replace all occurence regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all occurent of `", ]"` to `"]"`

I tried:

```
 const str = 'website , ] asdf asdf , asdf'

 str.replace('/, ]/g',']')
```

Nothing happens

Comment: `str.replace(', ]', "]");`

Comment: This does not place all occurences

Comment: 1) regex literals are written without quotes, 2) you have to assign the result of `replace`

Comment: str.replace(/, ]/g,']') will replace all occurences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace('/, ]/g',']')` doesn't change `str` in-place. You must assign the result to another string variable:

```
var result = str.replace('/, ]/g',']');
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to find all `, ]` occurences is `/, ]/g`.

You should also store the new string returned by the `replace()` method.

```js
const str = 'website , ] asdf asdf , asdf';

const result = str.replace(/, ]/g, ']');
 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace` and supply a regexp with the global flag to replace all of the occurrences.

Use `\s` any type of space
Use `\]` to match the `]`

```js
const str = "website , ] asdf asdf , asdf";
console.log(str.replace(/,\s\]/g, "]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
str.replace(/, ]/gm,"]");
```

[online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/rH5cGI/1/)

[code generator](https://regex101.com/r/rH5cGI/1/codegen?language=javascript)